# Is it possible to update the inital state if the update function was passed in as props and its used in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 import React , {useState} from "react"
    import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent"
    
    const App = () => {
      const [name , setName] = useState(asd);
        return (
         <ChildComponent name = {name} setName = {setName}/>
          )
    export default App;

    import React from "react"
    const ChildComponent = (props) => {
        const handleClick = (props) => {
         props.setName(null)
    }
      return(
        <button onClick = {() => handleClick(props)}> X </button>
   <p>{props.name}</p>
          )
    }
    export default ChildComponent;
```

I want to change the value of current state 'name' from asd to null or an empty string by passing the setName function as props to ChildComponent and then accessing that function as props.setName in the child component. But its not updating the current state "name".

Comment: you have couple of wrong code. 1. you are not returning a single element from child component. 2. used undefined variable in `useState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the `props` as param of `handleClick` it will replace the children component variable `props`. So you can do this instead

```
const handleClick = () => {
         props.setName(null)
    }
```

and call it

```
<button onClick = {() => handleClick()}> X </button>
```

or call it like this (from @geoffrey)

```
<button onClick = {handleClick}> X </button>
```

Comment: `<button onClick = {handleClick}> X </button>` will do

Comment: Yes it will do as well, thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
const App = () => {
        const [name , setName] = useState('asd');
        return (
          <ChildComponent name = {name} setName = {setName}/>
         )
      }
export default App;
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
        const handleClick = (props) => {
          props.setName(null)
      }
        return(
          <>
            <button onClick = {() => handleClick(props)}> X </button>
            <p>{props.name}</p>
          </>
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [ihsan-fajar-ramadhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11561888/ihsan-fajar-ramadhan) said, you don't need to pass props parameter in the handleClick function.

Also, I would suggest to spread the props to get a clearer idea of what your code is doing something like:

```
const ChildComponent = ({name, setName}) => {
  const handleClick = (props) => {
    setName(null)
  }

  return(
    <>
      <button onClick = {() => handleClick()}> X </button>
      <p>{name}</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const [name , setName] = useState("asd");
  return (
    <ChildComponent name = {name} setName = {setName}/>
  );
}
```

The initial state of the child component will depend on this line in the parent component:

```
const [name , setName] = useState("asd");
```